# Selecting children elements from a <ul>

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

So I want to select the "href" attribute from all the element that are in a list. So in my case I want to get link from the a element.

So I've trief 2 diffrent each loops.

Html and JS Example:

```html
<ul id="product_list">
    <li>
        <div class="class1">
            <div class="class2>
                <div class="class3">
                    <span class="productPic"></span>
                    <a class="link" href="www.THISLINK.com"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="title"></div>
                <div class="logos"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="class1">
            <div class="class2>
                <div class="class3">
                    <span class="productPic"></span>
                    <a class="link" href="www.THISLINK.com"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="title"></div>
                <div class="logos"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="class1">
            <div class="class2>
                <div class="class3">
                    <span class="productPic"></span>
                    <a class="link" href="www.THISLINK.com"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="title"></div>
                <div class="logos"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
let $ = cheerio.load(resp);
        $('#product_list > li').each((index,element) => {
            console.log($this).children('.link').attr('href');
        }
        $('.link').each((index,element) => {
            console.log($this).attr('href')
        }
```

I'm only getting 'undefined' as result.

Comment: `$this` is never defined, use `element` instead

Comment: Also console.log doesn't have a .children function you can chain to it and are you not overriding jquery's $ by setting it to cheerio.load?

Comment: Your bracket is not closed at the end of console.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#product_list .link').each(function(index, el){console.log($(el).attr('href'))})
```

Comment: You can improve the quality of your answer by adding a few words of explanation instead of only posting a piece of code.

Comment: This is self-explanatory. This code should be used instead of that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is called `$(this)` and not `$this`.
This change will at least give you all the results you want. If you now just want the results that actually contain information, you should either use the second each loop or you can use `$('[href]')`.

Answer (score 0):

With map and es6 you would do:

```
const hrefs = $('#product_list > li .link').map((i, el) => el.attr('href')).get()
```

Note the get() at the end which turns it into a js array